# Uninstall Ubuntu Studio

Tags: uninstall, ubuntu-studio

Technically a duplicate question but I only saw one post like this and it was from 8 years ago. I installed Ubuntu Studio on top of my existing installation of Ubuntu 20.04.1 and I'd like to remove all of the Ubuntu Studio packages, but leave the existing Ubuntu install instead of just backing up and reinstalling completely. What command would I run to do that?

Comment: Ubuntu Studio **is** Ubuntu.  I suggest just removing whatever packages you don't need.  You can use `apt` or the software center.  There is no magic command that will restore your device to "stock" Ubuntu.  If you want that, reinstall.

Comment: Did you follow something like [these directions](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-ubuntu-studio-desktop-environment-on-ubuntu-20-04)?

Comment: @KGIII I actually followed [this guide.](https://ubuntustudio.org/ubuntu-studio-installer/)

Comment: Fortunately, those names are (mostly) the same names of the packages that they installed. I'm not sure about one, the low-latency kernel. But, you should be able to `sudo apt remove $x`, where $x is the name(s) of the packages. That should clean up some of it. Honestly, if I were in your place, I'd back up my /home directory and just do a clean install.

Comment: I have used `sudo apt-get purge ubuntustudio- `.  With TAB autocompletion, you get the list of installed package.   I have used also `sudo apt-get purge ubuntustudio-look`.  Yet it does not seem to work completely.  Doing a clean install is last resort because you loose configuration, drivers...

Comment: We also need to get rid of low latency kernel.

Comment: `sudo apt-get purge ubuntustudio-look` will not remove leftover dependencies, use `sudo apt autoremove` to get rid of them. Use `sudo apt-get purge -- autoremove ubuntustudio-look` to do this in one step. Make sure to read `apt`'s output carefully before you confirm the action, it could remove essential packages, so be warned.